# Detailed grouping by date windows explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-8, windows-xp

Now, Windows 10 (and maybe Winodws 8) is showing "A long time ago" instead of "Last Year"... like it was in Windows XP.

I also think there was also "Two Years ago", and only then if there is old enough files and folders it was "A long time ago"...

Actually, I can provide a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wdBG.jpg

The groups are also more specific and detailed about shorter periods of time.

I use Windows 10 all the time since its arrival, but still I miss the XP file grouping by date.

Answer (score 3):

I've never found nor seen a way to modify the grouping categories when using `Group by` in **Explorer**.
However, the ***Libraries*** (the true Libraries, which are in essence a saved search) have the additonal `Arrange by >` context menu entries, some of which offer ***stacks***, where the group appears as a single item that can then be viewed like a subfolder. The `Arrang by` options vary according to the optimization specified in the library's `Properties`:

[image]

Here, I created a Library that refences my `Documents` folder, but specifies `Pictures` as the content. Because a Pictures library offers two date-related arrangements: Month (presented in stacks) and Day (groups with headers):
[image]
[image]

Also, when you select a Month stack, its contents will be grouped by Day:

[image]

To the best of my knowledge, this is the best you can do without resorting to 3rd-party software that might offer more options.